# How can I send my updated data to a widget which has been already called in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using CustomPainter widget to draw on a canvas. After some time Streambuilder provides me with new data for CustomPainter. And I would like to draw on the same CustomPainter with the new updated data i.e I want to send tempList from Streambuilder to Drawing widget in CustomPaint. 
Should i be using a callback or a key, how will that be used if so, since I'm new to those concepts. I read similar questions but couldn't understand how it will help solve my problem.
Here is my widget hierarchy, please ignore my formatting

```
 Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    child: GestureDetector(
//                  some other widgets
                      child: Container(

                        child: ClipRect(

                          child: CustomPaint(
                            size: Size.infinite,
                            painter: Drawing(
                              pointsList: pointsList,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        color: canvasBackgroundColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child:
              StreamBuilder(
                  stream: channel.stream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError){
                      String receivedData = snapshot.data.toString();
                      tempList = receivedMessage(receivedData);
                      print(tempList);
                      return Text("tempList");
                    }
                    else
                      return Text("No Data");
              }
          )
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the widget that you want to rebuild after getting data again in-stream builder and when every time new data comes your widget will rebuild automatically that's why it have a builder method.

Comment: Thanks this helped me understand the streambuilder better and I was able to use it properly. @UTKARSH